# Popup On-Screen Keyboard On Text-box Focus Event in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I m Working On windows 8.1 metro app, This app is working on Kiosk Machine and no physical keyboard attach to Machine. I have Some Text-Box and i want to Auto pop-up on-screen Keyboard when user touch on text-box.

Comment: Please add some more details on it and do add some code too.

Comment: Since its touch wont the windows default keyboard come up?? or you dont want that and you want to create your custom keyboard?

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this

```
TextBox1.GotFocus += PopupKeyBoard();

protected void PopupKeyBoard(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink\TabTip.exe");
    if (sender is TextBox) { (sender as TextBox).SelectAll(); }
}
```

Comment: Process.Start Not Supported By Windows Store app i m Already tried this.

Comment: I think that is because your application is not in Tablet mode. Have a look at this link

http://www.windowscentral.com/how-force-tablet-mode-windows-10

Comment: thanks for your help  But on-screen  Keyboard does not appear in table mode even i remove my keyboard from machine.